# Does Elzinga & Hearn algorithm depend on initial points

Tags: optimization, algorithms, circles, discrete-geometry, discrete-optimization

> Elzinga & Hearn is an algorithm which find the smallest enclosing circle of $n$ points in plane. I wonder is it a good idea to initialize the algorithm of Elzinga & Hearn with the two points farthest apart?

Comment: Do you have a reference to the algorithm or to an analysis of the algorithm?

Comment: Alternatively, are you stuck using this algorithm, or can you use one of the newer alternatives that run in linear time?  For instance, Welzl's https://dx.doi.org/10.1007%2FBFb0038202

Comment: Additionally, how do you compute the pair that is farthest apart in less than $O(n^2)$ time?

Comment: @EricTowers Thank you for your suggestion. But I am only interested in Elzinga algorithm. Finding 2 farthest point apart is O(n) time and Elzinga & Hearn is O($n^2$). I am just curious if the initialization would effect on the running time or it would save some O(1) time. I guess that is true but I am not able to figure out it.

Comment: An algorithm to find the two farthest points in a set in linear time would be quite a breakthrough.  This is usually done *after* computing a convex hull (at cost $O(n \log n)$) and then using the rotating calipers method, for an additional $O(n)$.

Comment: Thank @EricTowers. I search on Internet but I am not sure about the correctness of information. Maybe they are wrong. Thank you !